# Attaching variable to end of asp hyperlink in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hyperlink

I am trying to customize my hyperlink to attach a variable Program Id at the end of each link depending on which Program Id is being used.

I Created my hyperlink and added the wikiLink.NavagateUrl to be the link plus the variable ProgrammId the issue is only the link is being attached and not the link with Program ID.

For example, if Program Id is 5(our variable) and I run this code the hyperlink when clicked goes to https://www.Example.com/ and not to https://www.Example.com/5 the link with the program id added

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="wikiLink" runat="server" Text="Link to Wiki page" </asp:HyperLink>
```

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ProgramID = 5;

        wikiLink.NavagateUrl  = "https://www.Example.com/" + ProgramID; 
    }
```

Comment: What's the question? You've stated your intentions, but what are you having problems with?

Comment: Sorry about that, I wanted to properly attach the program Id variable to the hyper link so far code works but doesn't add the Program Id variable @gunr2171

Comment: `<asp:HyperLink ID="wikiLink" runat="server" Text="Link to Wiki page" </asp:HyperLink>` this is design time. This --> `"https://www.Example.com/" + ProgramID` you will see in the page source at runtime as something like `https://www.Example.com/5`

Comment: @T.S. you see that is what I have been trying but the Program is never attached it stays https://www.Example.com/ I tired to ToString my Program Id just in case the type was a issue but it still didn't work

Comment: what does this mean --> `only https://www.Example.com/ **gets ran**`

Comment: Where does `ProgramID` comes from? Apparently it is null or empty

Comment: Please review [mcve]. You need to provide a complete (yet still minimal) example when you ask a question. We shouldn't have to keep asking for more details in a trivial piece of code like this, as following the [mvce] guidance should give us everything we need.

Comment: @T.S.  by that I mean the hyper link when clicked is opening that link and not the link with programId attached to the end. Sorry for making this more diffuclt then it had to be.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forget to close the open hyperlink tag with **'>'** and that you are misspelled the hyperlink property name. Try to write:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="wikiLink" runat="server" Text="Link to Wiki page"></asp:HyperLink>
```

in the web page and

```
wikiLink.NavigateUrl = "https://www.Example.com/" + ProgramID;
```

in the ".cs" file.

Comment: Thanks I cant believe I forgot to close it out , I also forgot to call my method that was setting the Program Id within the method. So that's why it was returning Null